# Broadcast Receiver not responding

Tags: android

Can any one let me know what is the best practise to do when there is a BroadcastReceiver that hasn't finished executing within 10 seconds

Comment: Well you are a little vague on the conditions that _cause_ it to run for 10+ seconds, I would re-write the code. Why does your BroadcastReceiver need to run for so long? If you are downloading data, you should move this off of the main thread...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sam is right. All long processing can not be done on UI(Main) thread. Use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) for example.

Comment: I am using Airpush in my application that has a broadcast receiver in it. I have noticed that the irresponsiveness of my app came after the integration of airpush but on the same time people are using it to perfectioin this means there something wrong in my code. I keeps on broadcasting and at certaing instance it shows a ANR dialog even when app is close and user is doing something else

Comment: I can not help you with Airpush - I do not use it. But I would try to watch logs or if you can reproduce bug try to debug it. What processing is going on what threads...
Also in service if it is not done correctly, long processing can be on UI Thread. Also on my phone I can turn application to strict mode so screen flashes when there is some processing on UI thread.